# C++ recursive data types

Tags: c++

A bit of a noob question:
I need classes A and B such that A has a B* member and B has an A* member.

When compiling I get "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘B’ with no type". How can I get around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forward declare B (or A )

```
class B; //forward declaration of B

class A
{
   B *b;
};

class B
{
   A *a;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Forward declare one of class a or b.

```
class b; //forward declaration

class a{
//class a stuff
b* ptrtoB;

};


class b{
//class b stuff
a* ptrtoA;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also inline forward declare one of the classes if nothing else is using it: `class B* pMemberB;` al la C style